# scoped_dirXXXX_XXXXXXX not deleted automatically

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

9.0 and ChromeDriver 87.0.4280.20 and i running my tests with python 3.6.
Selenium web driver created scoped_dirXXXX_XXXXXXX in AppData\Local\Temp and not deleted automatically
when the script finish , this folder become over 50 GB every 3 days. i know that this folder should delete automatically after test is done.
Thank you !

Comment: are you getting new folder created each time ? or overwriting the existing one ? for me i am getting only one folder

Comment: im getting new folder each time,

Comment: And it's not deleting the previous ones ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the folder creation happens when driver throws any exception.

If the run ends gracefully then the folder is getting deleted

Eg:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    options=options)

driver.get("asdasd")
```

This will close the program without temp file being deleted.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    options=options)

driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

This will end the program gracefully and removes the temp file.

SO what you could do is delete tmp file before the test starts to run , either from script or in your CI/CD

**to delete from python use :**

```
   try:
        for f in glob.glob(R"C:\Users\Local\Temp\scopeD_dir*"):
            shutil.rmtree(f)
    except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

This throws an error because of access permission trying to delete even the currently used dir, thats why the try catch